# Laravel Many To Many Relationship between Three Models

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to create a relationship between the three models. My models are

Users

-- Database Structure

```
  id

  name

  ---
```

Books

-- Database Structure

```
  id

  name
```

BookShelf

-- Database Structure

```
  id

  name
```

1: User has many books and book belongs to many users

2: User's book belongs to one BookShelf and user's BookShelf has many books.

How can I define the relationship between these three models? I am building an application something like Goodreads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a `many to many` relationship between your `User` and `Book`, as well as a `many to many` between your `Book` and `BookShelf`.

This type of relationship is managed by a `pivot` table behind the scenes, so you will require two pivot tables.

**Pivot between User and Book**

1. Create your migration

```
php artisan make:migtration create_book_user_table
```

2. Define your relationship

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('book_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained();
        $table->foreignId('book_id')->constrained();
    });
}
```

**Pivot between Book and BookShelf**

1. Create your migration

```
php artisan make:migtration create_book_book_shelf_table
```

2. Define your relationship

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('book_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->foreignId('book_id')->constrained();
        $table->foreignId('book_shelf_id')->constrained();
    });
}
```

With the pivot tables create you can add the relationships to your models.

**User**

```
public function books()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Book::class);
}
```

**Book**

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
}

public function bookshelves()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(BookShelf::class);
}
```

**BookShelf**

```
public function books()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Book::class);
}
```

Now you have your relationships, you can access them on your `User`. As an example:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    $user = User::where('id', 1)->with(['books', 'books.bookshelves'])->first();
    return view('user', compact('user'));
});
```

**user.blade.php**

```
<h3>{{ $user->name }}</h3>

<h4>Books</h4>
@foreach ($user->books as $book)
    <h5>{{ $book->name }}</h5>
    <p>Can be found on @choice('shelf|shelves', $book->bookShelves()->count())</p>
    @foreach ($book->bookShelves as $shelf)
        <li>{{ $shelf->name }}</li>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

The above would iterate over each `Book` for the `$user` and then iterate over each of the `BookShelves` that `Book` is related to.

### Update

If a `Book` can only belong to one `Bookshelf`, you need to alter your `books` table.

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('books', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->foreignId('bookshelf_id')->constrained('book_shelves');
    });
}
```

You will also need to alter the relationship on your `Book` model:

```
public function bookshelf()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(BookShelf::class);
}
```

This way a `Book` can now only belong to `one` `Bookshelf`.

If a `User` can only have `one` `Bookshelf`, again you need to alter your `book_shelves` table:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('book_shelves', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained();
    });
}
```

Then add the relationship to your `User`.

```
public function bookshelf()
{
    return $this->hasOne(BookShelf::class);
}
```

You should then be able to access the `Bookshelf` for a `User` directly.

```
$user->bookshelf->books
```

Comment: I have updated the question for a better understanding. Kindly go through it again.

Answer (score 0):

> 1: User has many books and book belongs to many users

- `User` has a [`Many To Many` relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) with `Book`

  - ```
    // User model
    public function books()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Book::class, 'book_user');
    }
    ```
- `Book` has a [`Many To Many` relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) with `User`

  - ```
    // Book model
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'book_user');
    }
    ```

> 2: User's book belongs to many BookShelf and BookShelf has many books.

- `Book` has a [`Many To Many` relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) with `Bookshelf`

  - ```
    // Book model
    public function bookshelves()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Bookshelf::class, 'book_bookshelf');
    }
    ```
- `Bookshelf` has a [`Many To Many` relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) with `Book`

  - ```
    // Bookshelf model
    public function books()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Book::class, 'book_bookshelf');
    }
    ```

You'd need two pivot tables.

`book_user`

| column | migration |
| --- | --- |
| id | `$table->id()` |
| book_id | `$table->foreignId('book_id')->constrained('books')` |
| user_id | `$table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained('users')` |

`book_bookshelf`

| column | migration |
| --- | --- |
| id | `$table->id()` |
| book_id | `$table->foreignId('book_id')->constrained('books')` |
| bookshelf_id | `$table->foreignId('bookshelf_id')->constrained('bookshelves')` |

Comment: I have updated the question for a better understanding. Kindly go through it again.

Comment: My answer stays the same.

Comment: Okay. So I will be able to get the bookshelves of the user? If yes, then how does laravel know that we are asking this relationship with respect to the user, not with the respect to the current book?

Answer (score 0):

Let's start from first task:

1: User has many books and book belongs to many users

In this case it is many-to-many relationships. To implement this setup you need users table like this:

Users: id, name, someotherdata

then you need books table:

books: id, name, bookdata

and then you need the third table to connect them many to many:

users_books: id, book_id, user_id

In this case when you need all books which belongs to one user you can select from users_books where user_id=someuserid and join it with books table and you will receive all books which belongs to some user.

Visa versa you can receive all users who posses some particular book.

2: User's book belongs to one BookShelf and user's BookShelf has many books.

For this you would have to create table bookshelfs: id, name

And add foreign key to books table as bookshelf_id

Then your books table will look like this:

books: id, name, bookdata, bookshelf_id.

So when you need to get all books from shelf just filter select from books where bookshelf_id = someid